# ROS MoveIt PR2 Demo Launch Fails following tutorial

Tags: ros, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I am a newbie and was trying to follow the tutorial from here:moveit.ros.org/wiki/PR2/Rviz_Plugin/Quick_Start and when I tried launching roslaunch pr2_moveit_config demo.launch, I would get this message below:

All is well! Everyone is happy! You can start planning now!

[ INFO] [1385051476.430164298]: Loading robot model 'pr2'...
[ INFO] [1385051481.184719538]: Loading robot model 'pr2'...
[ INFO] [1385051482.547427811]: Loading robot model 'pr2'...
**[rviz_cehd_1050011_7612_1188156060-6] process has died [pid 7687, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/rviz/rviz -d /opt/ros/hydro/share/pr2_moveit_config/launch/moveit.rviz __name:=rviz_cehd_1050011_7612_1188156060 __log:=/home/willi/.ros/log/50fcfb64-52ca-11e3-b7fb-0024e8bf7cc6/rviz_cehd_1050011_7612_1188156060-6.log].
log file: /home/willi/.ros/log/50fcfb64-52ca-11e3-b7fb-0024e8bf7cc6/rviz_cehd_1050011_7612_1188156060-6*.log**

I searched around and it is a similar message but not exactly the same on this one://answers.ros.org/question/75769/ros-moveit-pr2-demo-launch-fails/. It fails at the end after saying all is well etc.

I just reinstall Ubuntu 12.0.4 64 bit because I thought my previous Ubuntu 12.0.4 32 bit is not working (always getting the same error 11) so I just freshly installed ROS Hydro, MoveIt and PR2 full and it is still failing and it's only a tutorial.

Can anyone give me an insights on what to do next?
Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103671/ros-moveit-pr2-demo-launch-fails-following-tutorial/) by [dragowill](https://answers.ros.org/users/9061/dragowill/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a total guess, but I experienced similar crashes with MoveIt on various machines and it turned out to be RViz rather than MoveIt that is crashing.  This seems to happen more often when RViz is trying to use hardware acceleration, so try turning telling RViz to use software rendering only before launching the PR2 MoveIt demo file like this:

```
$ export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1
$ roslaunch pr2_moveit_config demo.launch
```

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2013-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dragowill](https://answers.ros.org/users/9061/dragowill/) on 2013-11-21**:
Hi Patrick, thanks for responding. That seems to work for launching pr2 demo.launch now. However, every time I close Rviz that error message would show and have to use ctrl c to get out of it from the terminal. Do you think it's a good idea to put LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 in .bashrc? Thanks. --willi

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-11-21**:
Glad that got you going.  I also have to Ctrl-C to exit MoveIt completely after closing RViz--not sure if others are experiencing the same thing.  I have "export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1" in my .bashrc since I was getting tired of RViz crashing.  You can do an "unset LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE" in a given terminal if you want to override it on the fly.

**Comment by [dragowill](https://answers.ros.org/users/9061/dragowill/) on 2013-11-21**:
Awesome. Thanks! and I just realized that it is mentioned on top of this page:wiki.ros.org/rviz/Troubleshooting and found out that my laptop has Intel Mobile 4 Graphics Controller. so I am definitely will put it in my .bashrc.